# updating a text view is causing an android app to crash

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, textview

I'm writing an android game where sprites come down the screen and the user taps them to remove them. When the sprite reaches the bottom of the screen the player lives decreases and the sprite is removed but the text view that displays the player lives doesn't update.

I have put an "update" call in the on touch listener that is used to kill the sprites and this updates everything fine (player score gets increased when a sprite is killed). But I can't figure out how to get the lives to update when a sprite reaches the bottom of the screen. Every time I try to make it update when a sprite is deleted the app just crashes. I'm using (TextView).setText() to update the text view which displays the score

The app uses openGL to render the sprites.

How do I make it update when a sprite is deleted?

This is the class where the screen is set up and it has the on touch listener in it too.

```
package com.JACSoft.game;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GamePlay extends Activity 
{
    public static GameGLSurfaceView mGLView;
    public static int PlayerScore = 0;
    public static int PlayerLives = 9;
    public static int counter = 0;
    static TextView PStatsView;         // creates text view to display stats
    static LinearLayout Stats;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Stats = new LinearLayout(this);             //creates an editable layout
    Stats.setOrientation(1);                                // makes it horizontal
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    mGLView = new GameGLSurfaceView(this);
    PStatsView = new TextView(this);
    PStatsView.setTextSize(20.0f);
    PStatsView.setText("Score : " + PlayerScore + "             " + "Lives : " + PlayerLives);          // puts the string version of score in the text view 
    Stats.addView(PStatsView);                              // adds views to layout
    Stats.addView(mGLView);                                 // adds views to layout
    setContentView(Stats);                                  // sets layout as the view
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{
    switch(event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
            GameGLRenderer.sprites.deleteSprite(event.getX(),event.getY(), 0);
            PStatsView.setText("Score : " + PlayerScore + "             " + "Lives : " + PlayerLives);          
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

this is the bit that says I cant access the text view from a different thread, but i have tried calling a function from the sprite delete thread that is in the main thread that then calls the setText function

```
11-22 19:06:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27971): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

this is what comes after that line

```
11-22 19:06:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27971):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4865)
11-22 19:06:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27971):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:979)
11-22 19:06:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4306)
11-22 19:06:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27971):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10519)
11-22 19:06:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27971):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10474)
11-22 19:06:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27971):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6598)
11-22 19:06:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27971):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3705)
11-22 19:06:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27971):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3563)
11-22 19:06:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27971):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3538)
11-22 19:06:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27971):    at com.JACSoft.game.GameSprites.deleteSprite(GameSprites.java:120)
11-22 19:06:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27971):    at com.JACSoft.game.GameSprite.BottomReached(GameSprite.java:61)
11-22 19:06:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27971):    at com.JACSoft.game.GameSprite.moveBallDown(GameSprite.java:51)
11-22 19:06:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27971):    at com.JACSoft.game.GameSprite.gravitate(GameSprite.java:25)
11-22 19:06:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27971):    at com.JACSoft.game.GameSprites.draw(GameSprites.java:60)
11-22 19:06:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27971):    at com.JACSoft.game.GameGLRenderer.onDrawFrame(GameGLRenderer.java:68)
11-22 19:06:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27971):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1516)
11-22 19:06:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27971):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

Comment: The app doesn't "just crash" - it gives you a rather detailed stack trace of what caused the crash, which you can lookup in LogCat. Without that, it's pretty much guesswork here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the sprites in each game loop and check whether any reached the bottom of the screen, then you delete it and update the player stats.

Many game frameworks have a seperate thread for drawing and updating game objects. Your problem might be that the `setText` method is called from that thread, and not from the UI thread. Add this method to your activity class:

```
public void setPStatsText(String text) {
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            PStatsView.setText(text);
        }
    }
}
```

and call it to change the text.

If this doesn't help, please post the exception message from logcat.

Comment: I tried this and it won't let me call it unless it's static, but if it's static it wont let me use "this"

Comment: You can pass a reference to your activity to the game framework, so you can access your activity object and call this method. Anyway, the exception confirms this is the error - calling `setText` from a different thread than the UI thread.